# Python numpy arrays staying integers

Tags: python

I'm currently taking a numerical methods class and wrote a function to carry out Gauss Elimination. I noticed that for some reason when carrying out operations on a numpy array, python fails to convert integers into floats. so I'm getting zeros instead of a float.
Here is the segment of the code that carries out the Gauss Elimination

```
for k in range(h - 1):
        p = k
        B = a[k, k]
        for i in range(k+1, l):
            if a[i, k] > B:
                B = a[i, k]
                p = i

        if p != k:
            a[[k, p]] = a[[p, k]]
            b[[k, p]] = b[[p, k]] 

        for i in range(k+1, l):
            s = a[i, k] / a[k, k]
            for g in range(l):
                a[i, g] = a[i, g] - s * a[k, g]
            
            b[i, 0] = b[i, 0] - s * b[k, 0]
```

Here is the input used when calling the function:

```
a = np.array([[8, 4, -1], [-2, 5, 1], [2, -1, 6]])
b = np.array([[11], [4], [7]])
print(GaussElim(a, b)[4])
```

Any Idea why this may be happening? I can circumvent the problem by just writing my inputs as floats, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. I'm running Python 3.9.7 on the latest version of VS Code.
I am using numpy arrays for my input matrices if that affects anything.

**Note: What I noticed was that the array elements are staying an integer and not being converted to floats when operated on. Changing my inputs into the numpy array to start as floats solves the issue, but I'd like to not have to write ".0" at the end of every input for cleanliness.

Comment: As a side note, you can just add "." at the end instead of ".0" to make it a float.

Comment: You can change the array values to floats in the `GausElim` class like this: `array.astype('float64')`

Comment: Init with `dtype` like `np.array([[8, 4, -1], [-2, 5, 1], [2, -1, 6]], dtype=np.float32)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Python is doing the operations as floats but since the arrays are `dtype=int64`, they are being cast back to integers in order to store them.

As @Ynjxsjmh comment mentions, you can explicitly set the `dtype` of the arrays to float at specification:

```
a = np.array([[8, 4, -1], [-2, 5, 1], [2, -1, 6]], dtype='float64')
b = np.array([[11], [4], [7]], dtype='float64')
```

Alternatively, since all elements in an array have the same type, you can just force it by adding a point to one of the numbers:

```
a = np.array([[8., 4, -1], [-2, 5, 1], [2, -1, 6]])
b = np.array([[11.], [4], [7]])
```

Comment: Thank you! That solves my question!
A follow-up question for future use:
If I wanted some elements to be an integer but others to be a float, how would you accomplish this? It appears that all your mentioned solutions would make the entire array either of integers or floats.

Comment: Also, is there a way to make it return integers instead of the x.00000000e+/-xx if the operation doesn't change it from an integer?

Comment: It is not possible for different entries of numpy arrays to be of different type. If you want that, I'd change the code to work with a list of lists (since lists allow any type). I don't know off-hand how to get what you want in terms of print formats, but I'd look at specifying a custom formatter within [numpy.set_printoptions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)

Comment: As @atony said, it's true that all of the cells in a numpy array have to be the same type. But there is another kind of data structure in NumPy called [structured arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html) where you can (up to a point) mix data types.